# 'New' Picture of the location? (CSS)

Tags: css, html

Wide and narrow screens is a problem.. How can I set the position of the picture? (site footer menu bar - fixed)

[Click on the image to see detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYVsu.png)

Can you help? Thank you!

*Menu bar code:*

```
     div.footer{ /* main*/
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
        border-top: 1px solid #222;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 12%;
        line-height: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 963px;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div.footer a {
        color: #999;
    }
    div.footer a:hover {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? It's also a little confusing to call your footer 'header'. Please add a link to a picture with expected output and real output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want that "new" image to appear in the right corner of one of your links. To do so you need to set position:relative to your link and position the image absolute. Something like this:

```
div.footer a {
    color: #999;
}
div.footer a img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

- You can set the top and right as big as you want